# How to find number of distinct solutions of equation $f(x) + f(x/2) =x$.

Tags: functional-equations

How to find number of distinct solutions of 
equation $f(x) + f(x/2) =x$.

by replacing x by x/2? and so on, at end i m left with 
f(0).

Comment: So $f(0)=0$, is that your conclusion?  Are there no other possible solutions?

Comment: @TheoBendit "The number of solutions to the given equation depends heavily on the function $f$." Mh, isn't $f$ the solution ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust I honestly thought they were solving for $x$. I also somehow misread the functional-equations tag as functional-analysis. Let's chalk this up to a careless reading on my part, and a lack of context on the asker's part.

Comment: @TheoBendit: ok, understood :-)

Answer (score 9):

Let $x=2^t$ so that $f(2^t)+f(2^{t-1})=2^t$ or $g(t)+g(t-1)=2^t$. We now have an ordinary linear recurrence. The homogeneous equation has the general solution

$$g(t)=(-1)^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\phi(\{t\})$$ where $\phi$ is an arbitrary function defined over $[0,1)$. This is because the sign alternates in successive unit intervals.

The non-homogeneous equation has the particular solution

$$g(t)=\frac232^t.$$

Finally the general solution in $x$ is

$$f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor}\phi(2^{\{\log_2 x\}})+\frac23x.$$

Below, an example smooth solution with $\phi(t)=\sin(\pi t)$ (giving  $\sin(\log_2 x)+\frac{2x}3$).

[image]

Note that there is an uncountable infinity of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$f\left(x\right)+f\left(\frac x2\right)=x,f\left(\frac x2\right)+f\left(\frac x4\right)=\frac x2\implies  f\left(x\right)-f\left(\frac x4\right)=\frac x2$$

$$f\left(x\right)-f\left(\frac x4\right)=\frac x2,f\left(\frac x4\right)+f\left(\frac x8\right)=\frac x4\implies  f\left(x\right)+f\left(\frac x8\right)=\frac{3x}4$$
$$\cdots$$
$$ f\left(x\right)+f\left(\frac x{2^{2n}}\right)=\left(\frac{2}3-\frac 1{2^{2n}}\right)x.$$

Hence you can be tempted to "take the limit"

$$f(x)+f(0)=\frac{2x}3$$

and conclude $$f(x)=\frac{2x}3.$$

But this doesn't work if $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ does not exist.

---

Disclaimer: the right term in the RHS, third equation, is not exact, but this doesn't change the conclusion. (It gives a possible solution, but not all of them.)